# HTML Tag without any view correspondence

Tags: html, angular

I would like to add an HTML tag without any view modification.
The reason is that I want to use only one attribute ( in angular is the *ngIf ) to show or not the inner arguments.

```
<ul>
  <li>First Value</li>
  <li>Second Value</li>
  <li>Third Value</li>
  <span *ngIf="something">
    <li>Fourth Value</li>
    <li>Fifth Value</li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

The span element somehow does the work, but it's not strictly allowed there, neither the DIV.
Is there any other solution other that setting **ngIf** for each **"li"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-container.

[Documentation of ng-container on angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#group-sibling-elements-with-ng-container)